# What is the total supply and mining rewards of the BEAM mimblewimble cyptocurrency?

Tags: money-supply, mimblewimble, beam

Beam is a implementation of the mimblewimble paper. The mainnet launch is happening tomorrow (jan-3). What is the total supply and mining block rewards for Beam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the website:**

Beam has a capped total supply, standing at 262,800,000 total coins. Our emission schedule is as follows:

- First year’s block reward is 80 coins per block
- Years 2,3,4 and 5 - 40 coins per block
- In years 6-9 the block reward is 25 coins.
- Afterwards, halving every four years until year 133, when emission stops

In the first five years of Beam existence, additional coins will be emitted to the Treasury:

- First year: 20 coins per block
- Years 2,3,4 and 5 - 10 coins per block

Source: https://www.beam.mw/faq/what-is-beams-emission-schedule